# How do I extract only the text from this html stored as a string in python?

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping

I have done some web scraping and stored the results in text files. I forgot to extract only the textual data, therefore I have stored the html as text inside the files.

I have loaded the files in to python, and I was wondering if there was anyway for me to extract only the text.

```
'home | thomson reuters\n\n\n\nvar digitaldata={"page":{"attributes":{"businessunit":"thomson reuters corporate","country":"global","language":"en"},"category":{"primarycategory":"thomson reuters corporate"},"pageinfo":{"pagetitle":"home | thomson reuters","pageid":"ec5c71ae 8958 4637 956a b3c3363a1990","pageurl":"https://www.thomsonreuters.com/en.html","pagename":"en:home page:thomson reuters corporate:global:en","pagetemplate":"tr_home page_template","documentage":"355","createdate":"2017 11 08","publishdate":"2018 10 24","pagetype":"home page"}},"product":{}};\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nwindow.cq = window.cq || {}\n\n\n(function(c,h){var f={};c.pubsub=f;var k=c.define;h(f);"function"===typeof k&&k.amd?k(function(){return f}):"object"===typeof exports&&(void 0!==module&&module.exports&&(exports=module.exports=f),exports.pubsub=f,module.exports=exports=f)})("object"===typeof window&&window||this,function(c){function h(a){for(var b in a)if(a.hasownproperty(b))return!0;return!1}function f(a){return function(){throw a;}}'
```

Above is an example of the data stored inside the text files, what I want the data to look like however, is just the text, so

```
'home | thomson reuters'
```

I could go back and edit my web scraping code, however I was wondering if there was anyway to salvage this data.

Comment: print(str.split("\n")[0])   # here 'str' is your text

Comment: Your problem should be cleaned before you save all the data while you are scraping all the information.

Comment: Try to choose better your xpath